# Copy Items from folder and append date to file name. File won't close after modification

Tags: powershell

I am having two issues. The first issue is appending a date to the file name after it is moved and the second is closing word after making the changes in the document.

```
###Stores the Month and Week###
$Month = Get-Date -UFormat %B
$Date  = Read-Host 'Enter Report Date (M-DD-YY)'

###Sets location of templates###
$Templates = "D:\Templates"

###Set Clients Name Variable###
$client_names = Get-ChildItem $Templates

###Creates shortcut variable for Working directory addresses###
$working_directory = "D:\Reports"
$New_Reports = "D:\Reports\$Date"

###Creates folder for new reports###
New-Item -Name $Date -ItemType directory -Path $working_directory

###Copies all documents in folder to New_Reports folder#####
for ($i=0; $i -lt $client_names.Count; $i++) {
 $client_name = $client_names[$i]
 Get-ChildItem $Templates -Filter *.docx | 
 Foreach-Object {
 $current_template_name = $_.FullName
 Copy-Item -Path $current_template_name -Destination $New_Reports 


  }

}
###Opens each file in New_Reports folder and modifies content#####
for ($i=0; $i -lt $New_Reports.Count; $i++) {
 $New_Report = $New_Reports[$i]
 Get-ChildItem $New_Reports -Filter *.docx | 
Foreach-Object {
 $current_template_name = $_.FullName
 $Doc = OpenWordDoc -Filename $current_template_name
 SearchAWord –Document $Doc -findText '*Date*' -replaceWithText $Date
 SaveAsWordDoc -Document $Doc -FileName $current_template_name

  }

}

Function OpenWordDoc($Filename)

{

$word=NEW-Object –comobject Word.Application

Return $word.documents.open($Filename)

}

Function SearchAWord($Document,$findtext,$replacewithtext)

{ 

$FindReplace=$Document.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find

$matchCase = $false;

$matchWholeWord = $true;

$matchWildCards = $false;

$matchSoundsLike = $false;

$matchAllWordForms = $false;

$forward = $true;

$format = $false;

$matchKashida = $false;

$matchDiacritics = $false;

$matchAlefHamza = $false;

$matchControl = $false;

$read_only = $false;

$visible = $true;

$replace = 2;

$wrap = 1;

$FindReplace.Execute($findText, $matchCase, $matchWholeWord, 
$matchWildCards, $matchSoundsLike, $matchAllWordForms, $forward, $wrap, 
$format, $replaceWithText, $replace, $matchKashida ,$matchDiacritics, 
$matchAlefHamza, $matchControl)

}

Function SaveAsWordDoc ($Document,$FileName)

{

$Document.Saveas([REF]$FileName)

$Document.Close()

}
```

The script moves word document templates from the templates folder to a working directory using the date I enter.  I want to keep the original file name and then append the date I entered ($Date = 4-8-19).

Original file name: Document.docx

New Name: Document 4-8-19.docx

I then modify the content in the word document to add that same date and save the file but after the save the word document does not close properly and can still be seen in the running process.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide a *minimal reproducible snippet*? Would your script close word document properly without editing?

Comment: You create word com objects all the time, but never close and release them from memory, so the process(es) live on. At some point you will run out of memory like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for renaming, we can use the following to update the files in your `$New_Reports` path.

```
Get-ChildItem $New_Reports -Filter *.docx | Rename-Item -NewName {"{0} {1}{2}" -f ($_.basename, $date, $_.extension)}
```

As for the other issue... When I tested your script what I'm seeing is that the file is closing, but Word is not. This is evident by the fact that once `SaveAsWordDoc` is called for a file, it can be manually opened and editable in Word.

To fix this you'll need to `quit()` from Word. It might take a few seconds, but you will see it drop from your running processes.

In order to accomplish this and still use your functions I updated `OpenWordDoc` and `SaveAsWordDoc` to preserve the `$word` variable you created already.

So now `OpenWordDoc` returns `$word` as well...

```
Function OpenWordDoc($Filename)

{

$word=NEW-Object –comobject Word.Application

Return $word, $word.documents.open($Filename)

}
```

And then the `SaveAsWordDoc` function takes `$word` and issues a `quit()` when we're done...

```
Function SaveAsWordDoc ($word, $Document,$FileName)

{

$Document.Saveas($FileName)

$Document.Close()

$word.quit()

}
```

Now when we call `OpenWordDoc` for each item we assign both `$word` and `$Doc`

```
$word, $Doc = OpenWordDoc -Filename $current_template_name
```

And when we save, we're including `$word` as well

```
SaveAsWordDoc -word $word -Document $Doc -FileName $current_template_name
```

...
Apart from this you have some sections that could be simplified

Copying the files could be reduced to one line:

```
###Copies all documents in folder to New_Reports folder#####
Get-ChildItem $Templates -Filter *.docx | Copy-Item -Destination $New_Reports
```

And the outside `for` loop to open each file is redundant and that section could be shortened to something like:

```
###Opens each file in New_Reports folder and modifies content#####
Get-ChildItem $New_Reports -Filter *.docx | 
Foreach-Object {
 $current_template_name = $_.FullName
 $word, $Doc = OpenWordDoc -Filename $current_template_name
 SearchAWord –Document $Doc -findText '*Date*' -replaceWithText $Date
 SaveAsWordDoc -word $word -Document $Doc -FileName $current_template_name
}
```

Comment: Why not create just one script-scoped $word com object before the loop, use that for all documents and after the loop (when all docs are modified) quit and release the $word object? `$word.Quit(); [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($word) | Out-Null; [System.GC]::Collect(); [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()`

Comment: I agree, that would be the better way to do it for the presented case and remove the need for two of the OP's functions. As I mentioned, I was trying to solve the issue while still using the (slightly altered) functions.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I made the changes and it works great.  The script is running a little faster as well.